# php undefined offset in for loop

Tags: php, for-loop, laravel-5

This has baffled me for quit a while. I want to compare my data with the data coming next to determine when to change the row.

```
<?php
    $seasons; // laravel eloquent model from controller  
    $i = 0;
    $max = count($seasons);

    for($i; $i<$max; $i++):
        $x = $i+1;
        print_r($seasons[$i]);  // ok 
        print_r($seasons[1]);   // ok 
        print_r($seasons[0+1]); // ok 
        print_r($seasons[$x]);  // undefined  
        print_r($seasons[$i+1]); // undefined 
    endfor;
?>
```

Comment: ok, i think i know why now. b/c $x will be more than max index in array, so throw undefined error

Comment: `$max = count($seasons) - 1; ` an array starts at `0`, count starts at `1`

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    $seasons; // laravel eloquent model from controller  
    $i = 0;
    $max = count($seasons);

    for($i; $i<$max; $i++):
        $x = $i+1;
        print_r($seasons[$i]);  // ok 
        print_r($seasons[1]);   // ok 
        print_r($seasons[0+1]); // ok 
        if(isset($seasons[$x])){
            print_r($seasons[$x]);  // undefined  
        }
    endfor;
?>
```

By the way, $x and $i+1 these both lines are same. because $x = $i + 1; and again you are doing $i + 1.

Answer (score 0):

i over look that $x could be over the array index limit at the last loop, so i put in a check to solve the problem.  if someone else have better way of doing it, let me know too.

```
$i = 0;
$max = count($seasons);

for($i; $i<$max; $i++):
    $x = $i+1;
    if($x < $max): 
        if($seasons[$i]->month != $seasons[$x]->month)
            // do something 
        endif
    endif;
endfor;
```

Comment: In loop, above code is parsing 2 if conditions while it can be done in one if using isset index.